# Laravel Query: How to convert boolean 1 and 0 into 'passed' or 'failed'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I currently have a query where it shows the Quiz and the users who have taken it, including the total points of the quiz, name, number of correct answers and lastly the 'status' which is the 1 or 0 or the passed or failed.

I want to show in the status if it is 'passed' or 'failed' instead of 1 or 0.

```
public function getQuizInfoByQuizID(Request $request, $id){

$remarks = DB::table('user_scores')->where('quiz_id',$id)
->Join('quiz_information','quiz_information.id', '=', 'quiz_id')
->rightJoin('users','users.id', '=', 'user_id')
->select('quiz_information.quiz_title AS Quiz Title','total_points AS Points','number_of_correct_answers',
'users.name AS Name','remarks as STATUS') 
->groupBy('quiz_title','total_points','number_of_correct_answers','name','remarks')
->get()
->toArray();


return response(['message'=>"Remarks successfuly shown", 
'error'=>false,
'error code'=>200,
'line'=>"line".__LINE__."".basename(__LINE__),
'quizRemarks'=>$remarks],200,[],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can process this in get function. I need your code more in get function

Comment: There's multiple ways to do this but I think the best approach to this is to ditch the `DB` facade and the joins and go for eloquent models with relationships and use an accessor. It will make the code a lot more legible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` statement in `select` query like `if(remarks=1,"passed","faild")`.

So replace this instead of `select`:

```php
...->select('quiz_information.quiz_title AS Quiz Title','total_points AS Points','number_of_correct_answers',
'users.name AS Name',DB::raw('if(remarks=1,"passed","faild") as STATUS'))
```

But you can use the models ([Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)), then use accessor ([Eloquent accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)).

Comment: I am getting this error `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version`

Comment: Sorry. there was a syntax problem, fixed and answer updated